# Mac OSX installer in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans-platform

I'm useing Netbeans 7.4. I need to update the CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString keys in the Info.plist produced by the Mac OSX installer. I've poked around and have been unable to find how to do this. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Find your Netbeans 7.4.app, then:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + Click > Show Package Contents

Then navigate to:

```
Contents > Info.plist
```

and edit.